# JPA Specification with Subquery exists fails SQL Server syntax

Tags: java, sql-server, hibernate, jpa, subquery

Given 2 tables, Design Status (defines unique statuses by composite key) and Status Group (defines xref records from Design Status to User Group), I am trying to implement a Specification that returns Design Status records given a User Group.  Design Status has a 1-to-many relationship with Status Group.  Code below produces correct results via unit tests with H2, but fail in SQL Server at runtime with **Incorrect syntax near ','.** which I tracked down to the following `select (costatusgr1_.DESIGN_STAT_CD, costatusgr1_.PRODUCT_ID, costatusgr1_.USER_GROUP_ID)`.

If this clause is `select * from CO_STATUS_GROUP costatusgr1_` SQL Server will return proper results.  I am looking for help fixing my Specification to perform the select on subquery using either EXISTS or IN.

DDL as follows:

```
create table CO_DES_STATUS
(
    PRODUCT_ID int not null,
    DESIGN_STAT_CD char(2) not null,
    DESIGN_STAT_DESC varchar(30),
    constraint PK_DES_STATUS
        primary key (PRODUCT_ID, DESIGN_STAT_CD)
)
create table CO_STATUS_GROUP
(
    PRODUCT_ID int not null,
    DESIGN_STAT_CD char(2) not null,
    USER_GROUP_ID varchar(8) not null,
    constraint PK_STATUS_GROUP
        primary key (PRODUCT_ID, DESIGN_STAT_CD, USER_GROUP_ID)
)
```

Equivalent SQL as follows:

```
select ds.* from CO_DES_STATUS ds 
    inner join CO_STATUS_GROUP sg on ds.PRODUCT_ID=sg.PRODUCT_ID and ds.DESIGN_STAT_CD=sg.DESIGN_STAT_CD
where ds.PRODUCT_ID=123 and sg.USER_GROUP_ID='group1'
order by ds.DESIGN_STAT_SEQ_NUM
```

Using Entity for each table and compound key, CoDesStatus links 1-to-many to CoStatusGroup on productId and designStatCd.

Specification toPredicate method:

```
  public Predicate toPredicate(Root<CoDesStatus> root, CriteriaQuery<?> cq,
      CriteriaBuilder criteriaBuilder) {
    Subquery<CoStatusGroup> subquery = cq.subquery(CoStatusGroup.class);
    Root<CoStatusGroup> subqueryFrom = subquery.from(CoStatusGroup.class);
    Join<CoStatusGroup, CoDesStatus> subqueryJoin = subqueryFrom.join(CoStatusGroup_.coDesStatus);
    Predicate isAccessingUserPredicate = criteriaBuilder
        .equal(subqueryFrom.get(CoStatusGroup_.coSecurityUserGroup), this.accessingUserGroup);
    Predicate isProductPredicate = criteriaBuilder.equal(root.get(CoDesStatus_.id).get(CoDesStatusPK_.productId), coProd.getProductId());
    Predicate isParentEntityPredicate = criteriaBuilder
        .equal(subqueryJoin.get(CoDesStatus_.id), root.get(CoDesStatus_.id));
    subquery.select(subqueryFrom).where(isAccessingUserPredicate, isProductPredicate, isParentEntityPredicate);
    return criteriaBuilder.exists(subquery);
  }
```

Resulting Hibernate query:

```
Hibernate: select codesstatu0_.DESIGN_STAT_CD as DESIGN_S1_70_, codesstatu0_.PRODUCT_ID as PRODUCT_2_70_, codesstatu0_.DESIGN_STAT_DESC as DESIGN_S5_70_ from CO_DES_STATUS codesstatu0_ where exists (select (costatusgr1_.DESIGN_STAT_CD, costatusgr1_.PRODUCT_ID, costatusgr1_.USER_GROUP_ID) from CO_STATUS_GROUP costatusgr1_ inner join CO_DES_STATUS codesstatu2_ on costatusgr1_.DESIGN_STAT_CD=codesstatu2_.DESIGN_STAT_CD and costatusgr1_.PRODUCT_ID=codesstatu2_.PRODUCT_ID where costatusgr1_.USER_GROUP_ID='group1' and codesstatu0_.PRODUCT_ID=123 and codesstatu2_.DESIGN_STAT_CD=codesstatu0_.DESIGN_STAT_CD and codesstatu2_.PRODUCT_ID=codesstatu0_.PRODUCT_ID)
```

Error:

```
WARN  org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.spi.SqlExceptionHelper - SQL Error: 102, SQLState: S0001
ERROR org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.spi.SqlExceptionHelper - Incorrect syntax near ','.
```

Comment: Hello, did you try to validate the syntax of the generated query using Query Analyzer or other SQL Server tool?

Comment: Yes, using SQL Server console I got the same error as described.  However, once I changed the query to `where exists(select * from CO_STATUS_GROUP costatusgr1_` it works as expected.  The error is telling me that the comma(s) within this portion are invalid: `where exists(select **(costatusgr1_.DESIGN_STAT_CD, costatusgr1_.PRODUCT_ID, costatusgr1_.USER_GROUP_ID)** from CO_STATUS_GROUP costatusgr1_`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In an exists subquery it's better to just select a constant anyway, so just use the following instead:

```
  public Predicate toPredicate(Root<CoDesStatus> root, CriteriaQuery<?> cq,
      CriteriaBuilder criteriaBuilder) {
    Subquery<Integer> subquery = cq.subquery(Integer.class);
    Root<CoStatusGroup> subqueryFrom = subquery.from(CoStatusGroup.class);
    Join<CoStatusGroup, CoDesStatus> subqueryJoin = subqueryFrom.join(CoStatusGroup_.coDesStatus);
    Predicate isAccessingUserPredicate = criteriaBuilder
        .equal(subqueryFrom.get(CoStatusGroup_.coSecurityUserGroup), this.accessingUserGroup);
    Predicate isProductPredicate = criteriaBuilder.equal(root.get(CoDesStatus_.id).get(CoDesStatusPK_.productId), coProd.getProductId());
    Predicate isParentEntityPredicate = criteriaBuilder
        .equal(subqueryJoin.get(CoDesStatus_.id), root.get(CoDesStatus_.id));
    subquery.select(criteriaBuilder.literal(1)).where(isAccessingUserPredicate, isProductPredicate, isParentEntityPredicate);
    return criteriaBuilder.exists(subquery);
  }
```

Comment: Thanks Christian that appears to have solved my issue!